# Read all rows with pd.read_csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv, jupyter, data-processing

I'm using Python to read a file of 5,000,000 rows but currently it only reads 1,000,000 rows. The file is around 125mb.

I'm using the `pd.read_csv` function but this only leads to reading 1,000,000 rows of my file.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Wolcome to SO, Please provide your call that reads in the csv.

Comment: Also a sample of the csv would be nice

Comment: Please add piece of code which *only reads 1,000,000 rows out*

Comment: Are you sure the upload gets the full file?

Comment: To your question text add, as text, answers to: 1) Are you actually talking about displaying 1,000,000 rows? 2) How did you determine there where 5,000,000 rows in the file? 3) Are you sure those 5,000,000 rows are not wrapped lines that resolve to 1,000,000 actual lines.

Answer (score 0):

For reading long files in Python, I recommend using Dask:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
df = dd.read_csv('yourfile.csv')
```

For more information, visit the Dask documentation page:

https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/generated/dask.dataframe.read_csv.html